# How do I do a type assertion on an interface{} variable to test if it is a function?

Tags: callback, go, type-safety, type-assertion

I am attempting to write a function that accepts either some type of content of arbitrary type or a function that can generate and return an arbitrary type.  To do this, I have to be able to generally test if an argument is a function without testing for whether it is a function of return type X. How do I do this?  Might look something like the following:

```
func Blah(arbitrary interface{}) {
    var value interface{}

    if function, ok := arbitrary.(func interface{}); ok {
        value = function()
    } else {
        value = arbitrary
    }
    ...
}
```

This fails as is. Maybe a type assertion isn't the thing to use here. Or maybe I just don't know the syntax. Would appreciate any suggestions. Only thing I know to do at present is to divide this up into two functions, one that accepts data to be stored as is, and another that expects to get a function, but that seems overkill when in both cases the goal is simply to get a value and pass it on to the rest of the function.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Type assertion doesn't seem possible (static vs. runtime type checking: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21496374/6309). That leaves you with reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type assertions work on specific types. If you know that the type of the function always has type `func() interface{}`, then you can use:

```
if f, ok := arbitrary.(func() interface{}) {
    value = f()
} else {
    value = arbitrary
}
```

Note that the type `func() interface{}` is a function with return type `interface{}`, not a function with an arbitrary return type.

It's easy to wrap an arbitrary function to a `func() interface{}`:

```
func hello() string { return "hello" }

wrapped := func() interface{} { return hello() }
```

If you cannot arrange for the function to have return type `interface{}`, then you need to use reflection to test and call the function:

```
func isFunction(v interface{}) (func() interface{}, bool) {
  rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
  if rv.Kind() == reflect.Func {
    return func() interface{} {
        result := rv.Call(nil)
        if len(result) > 0 {
            return result[0].Interface()
        }
        return nil
    }, true
  }

  return nil, false
}

---

if f, ok := isFunction(arbitrary); ok {
    value = f
} else {
    value = arbitrary
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/yjAvxxbSMa)</kbd>

Comment: I didn't thought of type assertion on `func() interface{}`. +1

Comment: Really try to avoid reflection whenever possible, given its inherent inefficiencies.  I did try the type assertion method, but I'm getting an error: http://play.golang.org/p/FjlOLsu4sP

Comment: Ah yes, that would do it.  Stray func() floating around there from previous experiments, causing trouble.  Thanks.